# Query two tables and select one field from response

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am using the following code to query a row from two joined tables:

```
s.database.GetDatabase().Model(&dbUser).Related(&result, "Registrations")
```

However when i use select as follows:

```
s.database.GetDatabase().Model(&dbUser).Select("name").Related(&result, "Registrations")
```

it show the following error and returns zero records

> (pq: zero-length delimited identifier at or near """")

Comment: Seems like the issue is not coming from the go-orm library. the issue is on the postgresql itself. can you show the raw sql query generated from your statements?

Comment: try moving the select after related

Comment: @xpare how can this be done?

Comment: @Pierre just tried this it gave same error

Comment: @user666 try to enable the logging feature http://gorm.io/docs/logger.html

Comment: @xpare I got: SELECT * FROM ""  WHERE ("user_id" = '4') do you have any idea why adding select make the query text go wrong?

Comment: It should also be possible to manually create a query like `s.database.GetDatabase().Query(" select * from user as u join result as r on u.name = r.Registrations where user_id = '4' ")`? should `&result` not be `&dbResult` <- just a question. It just seems like you have some fields missing... You don't state on which field it must join the two tables on, or does it automatically check for one field to join? ie. `user_id` ?

Comment: in fact without the select part it works perfectly and return the row... what i am currently doing is doing a loop over the result to extract the needed field in a list. But it sounds really strange if gorm does not support selecting one field from a join query ....

Comment: Well, get the row object back and select the single property like that then